# GridView stops interacting after screen orientation changes

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, fragment

I have activity with two tabs, which implements two similiar fragments, each fragment consist of *GridView*, loading items through *AsyncTask* and it works fine until screen orientatation changes... After that its only possible to click on action bar and switch between tabs, but *GridViews* completely stops interacting with user: scrolling, clicking or anything else. Nothing but standart *onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)* and *onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)* are implemented.

I have no idea about this issue, need help.

**UPD**: Well, after each new orientation change one new instance of fragment appears.

**UPD2**: Deleted unneeded code.

Comment: Did you check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) regarding what happens with orientation changes?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is getting re-created on the orientation change.

Try adding android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" to your  settings in your manifest.  This will prevent your activity from being re-created.

Comment: Did not help.
Activity recreates and even display top of grid list, but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue!

The problem was in Activity.onCreate and tab creation mechanism.

Each time activity recreated after state change onCreate additionaly adds a new tab, so

```
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
```

check resolve problem. Here is the full, properly working OnCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("TabLabel")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<FileFragment>(
                        this, "TabTag", FileFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
    Log.d("Activity.OnCreate", "Creating Activity");

}
```